# How to init a pubspec.yaml?

Tags: dart, pubspec

Just like:

- `cargo init` in rust
- `go mod init` in go
- `yarn init` in javascript.

Comment: [`dart create`](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-create) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Official Google Dart package manager never supported such functionality and it was never announced that it was planned to implement this.
Alternatively, you can use third-party software for this.
Example, Stagehand - A Dart project generator.
https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand
This tool does not support generating files "pubspec.yaml but it support generating various kinds of projects from templates.
**Hint.**
if you want to use Stagehand on the command line, install it using pub global activate:

> pub global activate stagehand